# Geometry regular polygon inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality

Say we have $A_1A_2...A_n$ a regular polygon inscribed in a circle with radius 1 in the coordinate plane with $O(0,0)$. Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^nOA_i \geq n$.
In other words, through a translation, (if someone can prove it like this) let $z_1,z_2,...z_n\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z_i|=1, i\in{1,2,...,n}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i=0$. Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n|z-z_i| \geq n$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I proved this only with even n. If n is even then we take each vertex and the diametrically opposite one and using the triangle inequality in triangle $OA_iA_j$ we get that $OA_i+OA_j \geq 2$ with equality when O is the center of the polygon's circle. Adding up everything it gives the result. But when n is odd, the opposite side is the middle of the opposite arc which is more complicated.

Comment: $O$ isn't the centre of the polygon, it's just the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Here is a proof of a more general result: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h402960p2245050

Comment: Thanks I think it's enough for me. $OA_i+OA_j \geq 2$ because I was talking about the pairs of $i$ and $j$ where $A_i$ and $A_j$ are diametrically opposite points of the polygon on the circle and we know that the diameter is 2.

Comment: But isn't it wrong? $1-xx_i-yy_i$ could be negative so he should have taken the modulus when he square-rooted the inequality.

Comment: Note that $ \sum |a _i | \geq  | \sum a_i |$. So while they should have taken the modulus and $ XP_i = |1 - xx_i - yy_i|$, the described approach still works.

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought it will work like that but I was tired and I guess I did something wrong. Thanks!